# sum() as x not seeing x in where statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a mySQL statement with two joins like this:

```
SELECT a.userID,  sum(b.score) as totalScore, c.userName FROM b
  Inner Join a on b.noteID = a.noteID
  Inner Join user on c.userID =  a.userID
  Where totalScore != 0
  group by a.userID  order by totalScore desc
```

But when I run the query it can not decipher the sum that I labeled with the as

```
LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'totalScore' in 'where clause' 0.18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `having` clause instead

```
  select a.userID, c.userName, 
         sum(b.score) as totalScore
  FROM b
  Inner Join a on b.noteID = a.noteID
  Inner Join user on c.userID =  a.userID
  group by a.userID, c.userName 
  having totalScore != 0
  order by totalScore desc
```

1. You can't use alias names from the `select` in the `where` clause
2. `totalScore` is a value that refers to the whole group and not just a single record, so you have to put it in the `having`
3. You should not select `c.userName` since it is neither aggregated nor in the `group by` clause. In `strict` mode MySQL throws an error and other DB engines will always throw an error

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why no c.userName? I need to see that value for my output

Comment: And what value is that? Can there be more than one value for every `a.userId`? If not then add it to the `group by` clause. If there can be more than one value for each userId then you need to tell the DB which one to take for each group.

Comment: its the user name attached to the user id, all taken from different tables

Comment: So only one username for every userID - add it to the group by: `group by a.userID, c.username`

Comment: as long as it is MySQL and userID is unique, you can safely add username in select but not in group -- however it is not a valid SQL in non-MySQL